# How do I statically link the Visual C runtime into my program?

Tags: c++

This is kind of a duplicate question, but I never got a good answer from the other posts. I could compile and run my visual c++ programs on my pc really easily. However when I moved it to my other computer, it required a dll called msvcr10.dll. How do I statically compile/link this dll with my program?

Comment: Why is this question getting downvoted??? Because people cant answer it??

Comment: Choose **MultiThreaded** instead of **MultiThreaded DLL** as Runtime library in the Code Generation section of project properties.

Comment: _"This is kind of a duplicate question, but I never got a good answer from the other posts."_ That doesn't mean you should post a duplicate question.

Comment: @MattBall Then where the hell do i get an answer

Comment: @SusanYanders You do what *everyone else* on this site does, and post a bounty on your question, if you feel that it's not getting enough attention.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#bounty, and yes I know that doesn't help you _right now_ since you don't have much rep. Also, relax. I don't think swearing's going to help you get an answer, nor help us help you.

Comment: lol my reputation cant go down any further

Comment: @JonathonReinhart You make a good point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right-click your project, and select properties. Under **C/C++**, select **Code Generation**.  In there you'll see an option for "Runtime Library".  Select **Multi-threaded [Debug]** instead of **Mutli-threaded [Debug] DLL**.

[image]

Comment: Glad I could help. Please next time try a little harder to research the problem beforehand. This issue is found many places on SO and the Internet in general.